# $\big|P_n(x) - |x|\big| < 1/n$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ implies $\|P_n(f) - |f|\|_\infty < 1/n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

In Reed and Simon's book on functional analysis they prove that any closed subalgebra $B$ of $C_\mathbb{R}(X)$ with $1 \in B$ is a lattice. Their proof is short and understandable, but there is one inequality that I am having trouble understanding.

Let $f \in B$ and WLOG assume $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ that converges uniformly to $|x|$ on $[-1, 1]$, i.e.
$$\big| P_n(x) - |x| \big| \leq 1/n \quad \forall x \in [-1,1]. \tag{1}$$
What I have not understood is how they use the above to say that since $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$, it follows that
$$\|P_n(f) - |f| \|_\infty < 1/n. \tag{2}$$
How do we go from (1) to (2)?

My thoughts are that by definition of the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm, we have that
$$\|P_n(f) - |f| \|_\infty = \sup_{x \in X} \big|P_n(f(x)) - |f(x)|\big|.$$
But I am having trouble relating this to (1).

Comment: Just replace $x$ in (1) by $f(x)$. In (1) you should have $x \in [-1,1]$ instead of $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for catching the typo. How do we know that substituting $x$ by $f(x)$ doesn't change the inequality?

Comment: Because we know that $f(x) \in [-1,1]$ for every $x$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah yes that was careless of me. Thank you!

Comment: You can write this as an answer